# How to split text per paragraph based on length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am using RedCloth, Rails 3.

Currently I splitling a long text based based on string "-BREAK-".
How do I split text based on character length without splitting in the middle of a sentence.

E.g.,

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at purus eu nisl consequat mattis. Morbi pretium eros eget erat ornare elementum. 

Vivamus in dui sit amet tellus bibendum volutpat. Sed lorem sem, porttitor at mattis quis, volutpat sed quam. Vestibulum eu justo nec dui ullamcorper molestie. Sed eleifend malesuada mattis. Curabitur eleifend elit vitae justo feugiat iaculis. Etiam sed lectus eu quam suscipit fermentum id a sem. 

Phasellus sed odio eu urna gravida venenatis venenatis non justo. Praesent tincidunt velit adipiscing ligula pretium commodo. Cras blandit, nibh ac sagittis egestas, enim odio rutrum metus, vel hendrerit felis urna cursus odio. Maecenas elementum erat et arcu vulputate eu fermentum orci semper. Proin luctus purus sit amet nibh blandit cursus.
```

That will be comprise one page. It's about 794 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should split your text to single sentences.

Here's a simple, far-from-perfect way for doing this (I'm sure you could find plenty of more complete patterns elsewhere):

```
'Gsda asd. Gasd sasd. Tfed fdd.'.scan(/(.+?\.) ?/).map(&:first)
#=> ["Gsda asd.", "Gasd sasd.", "Tfed fdd."]
```

Then, you should join these sentences, keeping an eye of the paragraph length. You can use something like this:

```
# using words as units, but sentences are just the same:
s = ['foo', 'bar', 'beef', 'baz', 'hello', 'chunky', 'bacon']
LEN = 7 # minimum length of a paragraph
s.inject([]){|a,i|
  if !a.last || a.last.length > LEN
    a << i
  else
    a.last << " #{i}"
  end
  a
}
#=> ["foo bar beef", "baz hello", "chunky bacon"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any built in logic for this, so you should just look for "." with a nice regex also specifying that it has to be straight after a word (not whitespace), followed by a space and a capital letter.

Edit: that should give you an array of occurrences from which you can pick the one closest to the character limit.